# django admin actions with intermediate page Httresponseredirect doesn't work

Tags: python, django, action, admin

I'm newbie in django. I would like to make admin action with intermediate page. I use django 1.7. According to django 1.7 docs: admin action with intermediate page should return HttpResponseRedirect. But in my case just page refresh happens. My code is listed below, and if you need here is link to my github [repository](https://github.com/Akopov4/studentsdb/blob/master/src/studentsdb/students/admin.py) . Please help me to understand the reason of such behavior.

```
def update_group(modeladmin,request,queryset):
    if 'change_group' in request.POST:
        form=UpdateGroupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            group=form.cleaned_data['group']
            updated_group=queryset.update(student_group=group)
            counter=queryset.count()
            modeladmin.message_user(request,u"У %s студентів було змненно групу на %s")%(counter,group)

        if not form:
            form= UpdateGroupForm()
        return HttpResponseRedirect ('/students/change_group.html',{'students':queryset,'form':form,'title':u'Зміна групи'})

update_group.short_description=u'Перемістити у групу'

class StudenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...... some fields to display

    ..... some fields to display and filter


    def get_view_on_site_url(self, obj):
        return reverse ('students_edit',kwargs={'pk':obj.id})
```

Comment: Where does the xpages tag come into play?  that tag is currently used with IBM's XPages technology.  Is that being used here?

Comment: What happens if your first condition is not true?

Comment: nothing should happens. As example i have used this one brief tutorial: http://developers-club.com/posts/140409/

Comment: @David no, it's just Django